# Combine highlight-symbol-mode and hl-line-mode

Tags: colors, highlighting, hl-line-mode

I want to highlight the current symbol under the cursor as well as the current line, but with different background colors.

Combining `highlight-symbol-mode` and `hl-line-mode` only highlights the entire line with the hl-line-mode color.

I have [`hl-line+`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-line%2b.el) installed and have tried reducing the `hl-line-overlay-priority` option but that does not seem to work. The entire line still get the same background color.

Are there any other modes or settings I can set to make this work?

Answer (score 8):

`highlight-symbol-mode` uses text properties, not an overlay.

`hl-line-mode` uses an overlay, not text properties.

**Overlays always take precedence over text properties**, no matter how low the overlay priority is.

So without some coding or code tweaking, I don't see a solution.

---

However, if you use the [**Highlight**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) library ([**`highlight.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) then the solution is simple.

Just use command **`hlt-highlight-symbol`**.  It is bound by default to **`C-x X h s`**.

(All of the commands in this library are bound in keymap `hlt-map`, which is bound by default to prefix key `C-x X`.  If you don't find `C-x X` convenient, you can bind the keymap to another key.  Or if you want to use only some of the commands in the library, you can of course bind those individually to keys.)

Here is a screenshot, showing symbol `nb` highlighted and hl-line mode turned on. I use [`hl-line+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-line%2b.el), but that shouldn't matter here. I did nothing special -- no tweaking of overlay priorities etc.  I just loaded [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el) and [`hl-line+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-line%2b.el), turned on `hl-line-mode`, and used `hlt-highlight-symbol`.

[image]

Comment: That's too bad. Do you know of some other modes that fit together better?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with this info.